# Inaccurate Distance Traveled Values when using Core Location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am relatively new to swift and I am trying to add a feature to my app, which tracks the distance traveled within a constrained amount of time.

However, as I run the app, I am encountering multiple problems even though the latitude and longitude received by the phone is accurate:
1. The app only records change in position for a few seconds
2. The app records drastic movements even when the device is stationary.

Any and all help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class MWTCountdownViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var metersLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ConfirmTrialButton: UIButton!
var zeroTime = TimeInterval()
var timer : Timer = Timer()
var ref: DatabaseReference?

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var startLocation: CLLocation!
var lastLocation: CLLocation!
var distanceTraveled: Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ConfirmTrialButton.isHidden = true
    ConfirmTrialButton.isEnabled = false
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        distanceTraveled = 0.0
        startLocation = nil
        lastLocation = nil
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10

    } else {
        print("Need to Enable Location")
    }

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(MWTCountdownViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    zeroTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate


    ref = Database.database().reference()

}
func updateTime() {
    let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    var timePassed: TimeInterval = currentTime - zeroTime
    let minutes = UInt8(timePassed / 60.0)
    timePassed -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
    let seconds = UInt8(timePassed)
    timePassed -= TimeInterval(seconds)
    let millisecsX10 = UInt8(timePassed * 100)

    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strMSX10 = String(format: "%02d", millisecsX10)

    timerLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strMSX10)"

    if timerLabel.text == "06:00:00" {
        timer.invalidate()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        ConfirmTrialButton.isHidden = false
        ConfirmTrialButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = locations.first as CLLocation!
    } else if let location = locations.last {
        let lastDistance = lastLocation.distance(from: location)
        distanceTraveled += lastDistance
        let trimmedDistance = String(format: "%.2f", distanceTraveled)
        metersLabel.text = "\(trimmedDistance) m"
    }

    lastLocation = locations.last as CLLocation!
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate any sample code to add in order to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your current strategy for computing distance travelled is going to over-estimate the distance, potentially by a great deal.

Currently you assume that you can always add the distance between the last locations reported to `locationManager(didUpdateLocations:)` to your total distance traveled. Unfortunately that's not a safe assumption.

In the docs for [`startUpdatingLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation) we see that:

> the receiver generates update events primarily when the value in the distanceFilter property is exceeded. Updates may be delivered in other situations though. For example, the receiver may send another notification if the hardware gathers a more accurate location reading.

The initial location fix of the device may be *very* inaccurate. The first couple of location updates you receive may not indicate any movement of the device at all but rather just increasingly accurate measurements. At a minimum you should consider the [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy) of the new location to try to determine if you can use the data you received. E.g. if you get multiple measurements 10s of meters apart but which all have an accuracy of 100s of meters you really have no idea if the device has moved or not.

It may be worth noting here that [`desiredAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy) prevent the delivery of inaccurate locations, it just specifies how hard the device should work to get an increasingly accurate location.

> When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you requested. The location service delivers the initial event as quickly as possible. It then continues to determine the location with the accuracy you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary, when that data is available.

Even at its highest precision CLLocation data will contain a fair amount of jitter. Calculating the distance between every reported location will show a lot of movement even when the device remains stationary. Instead you may want to collect all the reported locations and use some sort of smoothing or curve fitting to estimate the actual path of travel.

Exactly what strategy you want to use here really depends on what assumptions you can make about device movement. Navigation apps will often pin estimated location to known roads. Running apps need to handle fairly tight loops so they can track running around a 60m wide track. A downhill skiing app might have to handle lots of lateral movement but be able to assume no significant backtracking uphill during a run.

Comment: Thanks Jonah. While I understand your logic and the flaws in my code, I cannot think of a way to implement such filtering. This app would track walking distance and needs to be pretty accurate. Could you provide further tips or sample code additions? Thanks.

Comment: Some options: You could try waiting for an accurate location fix before starting your tracking and fail if you can't obtain your desired accuracy (though that might make the app unusable indoors or in other poor reception environments). You could try building a bezier path out of your locations (and play with adjusting control points based on accuracy and movement direction) to get a guess at the actual path of travel. You could apply curve fitting like https://blog.demofox.org/2016/12/22/incremental-least-squares-curve-fitting/ to a sliding window (count or time) of locations.

Comment: If you know you only need to support a walking pace maybe you can average together reported locations every few seconds into a single estimated position, or you might find a way to disregard or modify locations which would require an unreasonable speed of travel.

Comment: I added a constraint of the distance change being less than a certain value. I estimated that the fastest realistic walking speed is 2.2 m/s. How often do the values refresh? From this, I can determine a realistic change in position.

Comment: Update: I added the constraint of the position change being less than 10 m to affect the distance traveled, but it is no longer recording any values after the first few seconds

Comment: I suggest you record all of the locations (and their accuracy) reported during some sample walk or two so you can look over an entire sequence when trying to decide how to estimate the actual distance travelled.